# Получение и запись в переменную данных node.js

Tags: javascript, html, node.js

при нажатии кнопки send нужно передать и записать данные, полученые с input полей в переменные (используется node.js)

```
    <h2 class="form-title">Input</h2>

    <div class="form-group">
      <input type="text" id="RecipAcNum" class="form-input" name="inpt" placeholder=" ">
      <label for="name" class="form-label">Recipient</label>
    </div>

    <div class="form-group">
      <input type="number" step="0.001" id="Amount" class="form-input" name="amount" placeholder=" ">
      <label for="name" class="form-label">Amount</label>
    </div>
  
      <input type="submit" class="form-button" value="send">

  </form>
```

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Если я правильно понял вопрос, то вот ответ

```
const express = require('express');
const bodyParser = require('body-parser');

const app = express();
app.use(bodyParser.urlencoded({ extended: true } ));

app.get('/', (req, res) => {
   res.send(`
<h2 class="form-title">Input</h2>
<form action="/" method="post">
  <div class="form-group">
    <input type="text" id="RecipAcNum" class="form-input" name="recipient" placeholder=" ">
    <label for="name" class="form-label">Recipient</label>
  </div>
  <div class="form-group">
    <input type="number" step="0.001" id="Amount" class="form-input" name="amount" placeholder=" ">
    <label for="name" class="form-label">Amount</label>
  </div>
  <input type="submit" class="form-button" value="send">
</form>
  `);
});

app.post('/', (req, res) => {
const recipient = req.body.recipient;
const amount = req.body.amount;

 // Do something with the received data
console.log('Recipient:', recipient);
console.log('Amount:', amount);

// Send a response back to the client
 res.send('Data received successfully.');
 });

 const port = 3000;
 app.listen(port, () => {
    console.log(`Server is running on port ${port}`);
 });
```

Comment: с этим кодом сервер запускается но при отправке заполненной формы ничего не происходит, имена в форме я поменял в соответствии с req.body.recipent/amount

Comment: Проверь сервер напиши код для гет запроса простой, и глянь получает ли сервак в принципе что-то

Comment: проверил axios.get, получил и вывел всю форму в консоль

Comment: А с этой формой Гет работает

Comment: я так вывел: const apiUrl = 'http://localhost:3000'; // Адрес сервера

axios.get(apiUrl)
  .then(response => {
    console.log(response.data); // Вывод полученных данных
  })
  .catch(error => {
    console.error(error);
  });

Comment: Вот адресс самой формы: http://127.0.0.1:5500/MainHT.html

Comment: а твой код видит сам факт запроса пост

Comment: походу нет, я поменял const port  на 5500, перешёл на http://localhost:5500/?recipient=nfdfdkfdjfkdf&amount=3, заполнил и отправил форму и ничего не произошло

Comment: так, работает, нужно было в теге form прописать method="post"

Comment: так все таки мой ответ правильный ?

Comment: да, только при переходе на  localhost:5500 у меня загружается только эта форма, без стилей и всего остального, а когда весь документ html запускается при помощи Live Server то этот код уже не работает. Мне получается нужно чтобы весь сайт был на этом localhost:5500?

Comment: ТАк вот и ответ. Live Server это штука которая работает так же. Поэтому когда она работает будут проблемы. Лучше просто как файл открыть

Comment: у меня сейчас считывает мой файл html, но не работают его стили css в отдельных файлах: app.use(express.static('Styles'));

app.get('/', (req, res) => {
   // Чтение файла MainHT.html
   fs.readFile('MainHT.html', 'utf8', (err, data) => {
     if (err) {
       console.error(err);
       res.status(500).send('Internal Server Error');
       return;
     }

     // Отправка содержимого файла в ответе сервера
     res.send(data);
   });
});

Comment: Тебе не обязательно через NODE выводить страницы.

Comment: Ты можешь открыть папку и просто запустить как обычный файл (мышкой). Просто действительно не все будет грузить так как ты выводишь файл не в том месте где он есть а значет относительные пути не пашут

Comment: мне нужно чтобы при запуске этого сервера также как и с использованием Live Server грузилась страница со всеми стилями

Comment: Тогда посмотри какой порт использует Live Server и используй другой

Comment: Типа 80 или 2050